# useEffect runs twice as much for each message sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am building a simple chat app with react, express and socket.io
I got stuck on receiving message from backend server.
Every time user receive some message, the  `useEffect` will runs approximately twice as much as before so after 5 or 6 received messages the app start really slow down.

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('mes', (data) => {
      setChat([...chat, data]);
    });
  }, [chat]);
```

any idea how to make it run just once every time user receive a message?

Whole code

```
import Chat from '../Chat/chat';
import queryString from 'query-string';
let socket;
const ChatRoom = ({ location }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');

  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [chat, setChat] = useState([]);
  const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4001/';

  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);
    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);

    socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.emit('join', { name, room });

    return () => {
      socket.emit('disconnect');
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

  const click = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('message', message);
    setMessage('');    
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('mes', (data) => {
      setChat([...chat, data]);
    });
  }, [chat]);

  return (
    <div className="ChatRoom-Container">
      {chat.map((mes, index) => {
        return <Chat text={mes.text} user={mes.user} key={index}></Chat>;
      })}
      <input
        value={message}
        className="ChatRoom-Input"
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          return e.key === 'Enter' ? click(e) : null;
        }}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatRoom;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`setChat(prev => next)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) instead of `setChat(value)` so you don't have to reference the previous value from the closure:

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('mes', (data) => {
    setChat(prev => [...prev, data]);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: thanks man, i don`t understand why it works but it does.

Comment: @KlopoCz the other answer has a decent explanation of why the other approach doesn't work. Essentially `socket.on('mes', ...)` was evaluated every time your `chat` variable changed, rather than only once when the component mounts.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('mes', (data) => {
      setChat([...chat, data]);
    });
  }, [chat]);
```

Here in your dependency array you have the chat variable as a dependency.
According to rules when the value of chat changes the effect runs.
as a result after you call `setChat()` one time it changes the value of chat and as a result it runs the effect one more time. that's why your effect is being called twice.